# Is it possible to use Azure SignalR Service in conjunction with local SignalR?

Tags: azure, .net-core, signalr, azure-signalr

We are in the process of evaluating Azure SignalR Service to potentially replace our current local SignalR service. We are using `.Net Core 2.2.402`

We tried the following:

```
services.AddSignalR();
services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(Configuration["Azure-SignalR:Connection-String"]);
```

And defined the routes and hubs as follows:

```
            app.UseAzureSignalR(route =>
            {
                route.MapHub<QueueHub>("/queue");
            });
            app.UseSignalR(route =>
            {
                route.MapHub<MessagesHub>("/message");
            });
```

Ideally we would like to use both in the same Web App but it seems to work only for one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Azure SignalR`, when a client start a connection with the server, your `.NET CORE` app redirects the connection to the Azure, so the connection is handled using `Azure SignalR` and you just provide the logic hub itself. And when you do `services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR(...)` it seems like the first registration that have only signalR is overrided by your second statement and this can be the reason you can not use both.